# Hurricane Names

Tags: pattern

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

We had a lot of hurricanes [this season](https://xkcd.com/944/), so we had to come up with a new naming convention for them. We had several possibilities, but in the end voted on one that would support having thousands of hurricanes in a single year. Unfortunately, we lost the page of notes that had the description of our new naming convention, and we all forgot it over the 3 day weekend, but we still want to use it. We did however get lucky in that we have a written list on the whiteboard of the names we could use for this year. Could you help us figure out our new hurricane naming convention?

#### List

> Bartholomew
> Patricia
> Ian
> Lea
> Brandon
> Ivory
> Grant
> Reda
> Steve
> Priscilla
> Brad
> Paige
> Craig
> Carol
> Jared
> Monique
> Weyman
> Sandra
> George
> Faye
> Kyle
> Beatrice
> Thomas
> Gina
> Bryan
> Felicia
> Matthew
> Ellen
> Holden
> Donna
> Brayden
> Pilar
> Seth
> Felicity
> Sam
> Sheryl
> Henry
> Anna
> Bob
> Leila
> Owan
> Georgia
> Ralph
> Lisa
> Sal
> Samantha
> Curtis
> Freida
> Will
> Penny
> Malcom
> Sarah
> Herald
> Sophia
> Usef
> Thea
> Wyatt
> Wilma
> Gregg
> Susan

Hint:

> I reexamined the board, and found a partially erased word that appears to read "Titles". Hopefully this helps. Also, one of my coworkers remembered an odd fact that no name that started with a 'Z' occurred in the first 50 names, but a Zachary did occur once after that and a Zoe much later.

Comment: Do you happen to have any examples of names that would not follow the convention?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie added a hint. hope it helps

Comment: @hexomino typo in my last comment to you, meant 50 not 500.

Comment: Just to clarify, in this system, would the first hurricane be named 'Bartholomew,' the second 'Patricia,' and so on?

Comment: @TwoBitOperation yes, that is correct

Comment: @Dragonrage Is it intentional that Bryan immediately precedes Matthew (no female name between)?

Comment: @hagfy no, it was not intentional. thanks for pointing that out. fixed it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The new naming convention is the following:

> The names are alternately male and female names based on the titles of xkcd comics. Each name shares the starting letter with the corresponding xkcd comic, and often also has a similar sound. So for example Bartholomew is based on [Barrel - Part 1](https://xkcd.com/1/), Patricia on [Petit Trees (sketch)](https://xkcd.com/2/), Ian on [Island (sketch)](https://xkcd.com/3/), etc. Zachary from the hint corresponds with [Zeppelin](https://xkcd.com/73/), and Zoe with [Zealous Autoconfig](https://xkcd.com/416/), which are the only titles starting with a 'Z'.

Comment: How on earth do you guys even find connections such as these...

Comment: Nicely done! :)